# PHP script that writes JSON code to txt file has missing spaces and line breaks. How to fix?

Tags: php, jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will "write" to a txt file in valid JSON format.

The script I've created basically works, except for some reason, the JSON code written to the txt file has no spaces or line breaks (it's just one big long line).

I've checked the JSON code (from the txt file) at http://jsonlint.com/ and http://www.jslint.com/.

JSON Lint says the txt file JSON code is "valid JSON"

JSLint, says Lots of errors due to "Missing space"

Here is the php script:

```
$cache = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/json.txt';

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/screen_name.json?count=1&include_rts=true&include_entities=true');   

    $cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');
        fwrite($cachefile, $data);
        fclose($cachefile);
```

I've tried adding different lines with json_decode and json_encode, but so far no luck.

Please tell me what needs to be added to this script so that the text file has the JSON format with the spaces and line breaks.

The generated txt file is being used in a jQuery script so it needs to have perfect JSON format.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: JSON is literal javascript data. If it displays without line breaks/spaces, then that's how the original data was. JSON isn't intended to be pretty to read, it's about sending javascript data structures in a plaintext format.

Comment: Add `var x = ` before it, then add a `;` after it, and it should validate as JavaScript for JSLint. JSON is not JavaScript. See http://json.org/

Comment: @artlung do you mean validate the JSON in JSONLint?

Comment: JSON is just a JavaScript object literal. For any chunk of json, whether that's `{"foo":1}` or `[0,5]` or whatever, if you turn it into a `var` declaration, it will be valid JavaScript. I don't know of a thing called JSONLint, I only know about JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 2):

It has no line breaks or spaces because this is what you get as response. Just put the URL in the address bar and you will see it.

JSLint is for validating *JavaScript code*, it does not make sense to use it for JSON.

As long as the JSON is valid (which seems to be the case), you are fine. No need to change anything. Every JSON parser ignores white spaces and line breaks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem and found the fix at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

It turns out that the txt file generated by the PHP script was not in UTF-8 format. I've updated the php script and it seems to be working now. Here is the final version of the php script:

$cache = dirname(**FILE**) . '/cache/json.txt';

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/screen_name.json?count=1&include_rts=true&include_entities=true');

```
$cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');
    fwrite($cachefile,utf8_encode($data));
    fclose($cachefile);
```

Thank you to those of you who gave answers, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As I recently found out, JSON != JavaScript.  A JSON string in JavaScript is just that, a string.  Given that, you really wouldn't want line breaks as they are not valid in javascript strings.

The errors probably relate to JSLint attempting to parse it as a JavaScript Object as I would guess there aren't quotes around the whole JSON string.  As long as JSON Lint says it is valid, then it is.

Comment: The errors are because JSLint is a JavaScript style checker, not a syntax checker (although it also does that). There's no need for JSON data to be pretty-printed and indented like JavaScript code, since it's intended for machine consumption, so JSLint's warnings are meaningless.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't use JSLint, I just configured my IDE to enforce style and it does syntax anyway.